# Finding the difference between a time and the current time

Tags: java, android, time, logic, timepicker

So I'm writing an app that has similar functionality to an alarm clock.  It asks for the user to input a time. But I've been stuck on how to figure this out for a while.

The method needs to find the difference in minutes between the user selected time, and the current time. Assuming that the user will always put in a time that is AFTER the current time (otherwise it wouldn't make sense to use my app), the difference would just be (userTimeInMins - currTimeInMins), where both are calculated by ((hours * 60) + minutes).

### BUT. Here's the problem:

Ex 1) If the current time is 10 PM, and the user enters in the time 2 AM. The above algorithm would say that the difference between the two times is (22 * 60 + 0) - (2 * 60 + 0), which is clearly incorrect because this would mean there is a difference of 20 hours between 10PM and 2 AM, when the difference is actually 4 hours. 
 
Ex 2) If the current time is 1PM, and the user enters in the time 2AM. The above algorithm would say that the difference between the two times is (13 * 60 + 0) - (2 * 60 + 0), which is again incorrect because this would mean there is a difference of 11 hours, when the difference is actually 13 hours.

### What I have so far

I've realized that for example 1 and for example 2, the difference in minutes can be calculated with 
(((24 + userHours) * 60) + userMinutes) - currTimeInMins

I'm struggling to come up with decision statements in the method to determine whether to use the first method or the second method to calculate the difference in minutes.

### The Code

```
// Listener for the time selection
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        String currAM_PM = "";
        String userAM_PM = "";

        // Get user AM/PM
        int hourToShow = 0;
        if (hourOfDay > 12){
            hourToShow = hourOfDay - 12;
            userAM_PM = "PM"
        }
        else if (hourOfDay == 12){
            hourToShow = hourOfDay;
            userAM_PM = "PM"
        }
        else{
            hourToShow = hourOfDay;
            userAM_PM = "AM"
        }

        // Update the time field to show the selected time in 12-hr format
        EditText timeField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTime);
        timeField.setText(hourToShow + ":" + minute + " " + userAM_PM);

        // Get current hour
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        String cHour = sdf.format(new Date());
        int currHour = Integer.parseInt(cHour);

        // Get current AM/PM
        if (currHour > 12){
            currAM_PM = "PM"
        }
        else if (currHour == 12){
            currAM_PM = "PM"
        }
        else{
            currAM_PM = "AM"
        }

        // Calculate the time to use
        // If the selected hour is less than the current hour AND am_pm is "AM"

        // THIS IS THE WHERE I NEED HELP
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        if(currAM_PM == "PM" && userAM_PM == "AM" .... ??????) { 
            //take 24, add the hour, use same minute. so that 3 am is 27:00.
            timeToUse = ((24 + hourOfDay) * 60) + minute;
        }
        else
            timeToUse = (hourOfDay * 60) + minute;
    }

       // timeToUse is then passed through an intent extra to the next activity
       // where the difference between it and the current time is calculated and used
       // for other purposes.
};
```

### Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Comment: Why don't you use `Date` object? it would be much more simple with this

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond  And use datepicker combined with timepicker? How would i find the difference in minutes in that case? I feel like it would be equally complicated.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I used a DatePickerDialog and a TimePickerDialog to load a Calendar object with the user selected year, month, etc.
Then I created a Date object, initializing it to cal.getDate().
I then loaded Date.getDate() into a long variable, giving the time in miliseconds from Jan 1, 1970.
I then divided this number by 60000 to get the time in minutes.

I did the same thing for the current date, and found the difference in between the two.
Thanks for all help.